# website load very slow when retrive data from firebase using datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, datatable, firebase-realtime-database

I just create simple web app from Firebase, Datatable, and ChartJS. I use minify version from CSS and JS file. But, when I finish to create this web app, I need to wait more than 10 seconds for all data displayed in my website. How I can make it load more faster ?
This is how I retrieve my data from firebase using datatable, I have more than 300 data. If I delete this code, everything is fine, now waiting for long time.

```js
var dbref   = firebase.database().ref('sensor');
dbref.on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
    var table =  $('#example1').DataTable( {
        destroy: true,
        //"bServerSide": true,
        //"bProcessing": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
            [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    });
    var dataSet = [snapshot.val().time, snapshot.val().temp, snapshot.val().date];
    table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
});
$('#example1').removeClass( 'display' ).addClass('table table-striped table-bordered');
```

Comment: My guess is that your `child_added` event is triggered 300 times at once as your data loads, and in that function you initialize a new DataTable *each time*, which is going to be slow. You only want to initialize the table once.

Comment: yah, because this is the only one i can retrive my data from firebase into Datatable. do you have any sugestion to make it more faster ? i need to wait more 24 seconds now.

Comment: Initialize the table only once, outside of the callback. The only code in the callback should be the `table.rows.add(...).draw();` part. If that doesn't help, you'll need to provide a live demo showing the problem for me to be able to help. Are you sure it's not just Firebase being slow? (it's not usually *that* slow though...)